# using Javascript to Save base64 image to File Path

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a base64 image string generated from a Signature panel. Now I want to get the base64 string to be converted to an Image and saved to a file Path Maybe on Drive C:\images How can I do something like this

```
function SaveBase64toImagePath(){

document.form1.base64TextString.value += obj.imageData;
var base64string = document.form1.base64TextString.value;

var fullString = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,+ base64string + " alt="">';

...

save to directory
}
```

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem from javascript directly, so saving to C:/images is not possible, but as suggested in the answer bellow you can "download" a file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

try es6 templates with ${variable};

```
var fullString = `<img src="data:image/png;base64${base64string}" alt="">`;
```

and then you can save image from img tag

[JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)